# Remove() do Entity Framework 6 só funciona ao recriar a conexão

Tags: banco-de-dados, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, orm

Estou criando uma aplicação utilizando EF6 e me deparei com um problema.
Estou utilizando o conceito de repositório e, quando rodo um delete (context.remove(obj)) e após isso recarrego o list e o datagrid, o percebo que o delete ainda não surtiu efeito. 
Então o delete é notado apenas quando eu fecho e abro novamente a tela, presumo que isso ocorra porque a conexão é recriada.

Segue abaixo o código responsável pela operação:

```
public void SalvarTodos()
    {
        _contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Excluir(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        _contexto.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList().ForEach(del => _contexto.Set<TEntity>().Remove(del));
    SalvarTodos();
    }
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

**EDIT:**

Método do repositório que recarrega os dados (retorna um IQueriable para posterior ToList()):

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _contexto.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Código da chamada da exclusão na ViewModel:

```
public void CarregaUsuarios()
    {
        Usuarios = new BindingList<Usuario>(_app.ObterTodos().ToList());
    }

    public bool CanDelete(object args)
    {
        return (usuarioSelected != null);
    }

    public void Delete(object args)
    {
        _app.Excluir(usuarioSelected.UsuarioId);
        CarregaUsuarios();
    }
```

O comando _app.ObterTodos notado acima possui o seguinte código, na camada de Aplicação:

```
public IQueryable<Usuario> ObterTodos()
    {
        return _repositorio.GetAll();
    }
```

Comment: Como é feita a seleção? Como você constrói suas grids?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu estou usando o padrão MVVM com WPF, e um BindingList<Usuario> na ViewModel... Passo um predicado lambda como parâmetro para o metodo Excluir:

Comment: O problema não me parece ser no EF. Me parece mais a memória das Grids que ainda está segurando os registros antigos.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o interessante é que quando eu chamo o método que recarrega os dados, o objeto IQueriable.ToList() retorna a mesma quantidade de registros. Logo, presumo que ha alguma transação presa (mesmo após chamar o contexto.SaveChanges()), a não ser que eu esteja enganado e o um ToList num objeto IQueriable não executa novamente a query na base. Irei editar a questão com o método do repositório que recarrega os dados.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Realmente verifiquei novamente que está sendo excluído imediate ao comando e o método de recarregamento também está OK, retornando todos menos o reg. excluído.  Certamente então o problema está no binding. Atualizei a questão com mais código, demonstrando como está sendo feito o binding...

Comment: Bom, me parece que logo após excluir você precisa renovar o binding, certo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez resolvido o problema. O binding estava sendo renovado, mas estava esquecendo de chamar o método NotifyPropertyChanged com o nome do list de usuarios... Então realmente o problema era na minha view e não no Entity. Muito obrigado!